# CloudFormation vieweing inactive/deleted change sets

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a cloudFormation stack which is in an active state. I executed a change set on the specific stack. 
Once executed, the change no longer appears as a value on the CloudFormation console. However if I do a describe-change-set operation with the change set ARN, I get the details of the changeset.

CloudFormation has an list-stacks API which lists deleted and active stacks. Is there any API to list inactive/expired/deleted change sets? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there doesn't appear to be any API that can list inactive (but not deleted) CloudFormation Change Sets.

The [`ListChangeSets`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_ListChangeSets.html) API is described as follows:

> Returns the ID and status of ***each active change set*** for a stack.

Once a Change Set is executed, it is not deleted, but enters the `EXECUTE_COMPLETE` state. The Change Set is still referenced by the stack in the [`Stack.ChangeSetId`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_Stack.html) property returned by the [`DescribeStacks`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeStacks.html) API, as used by the CloudFormation Console's **Change Sets** tab, though it no longer appears in the `ListChangeSets` output.

Beyond that, since Change Sets become unusable as soon as the stack has been updated, there's not really any other use for them. I'm also surprised they are still retained (indefinitely?). I wouldn't be surprised if a more explicit/controllable lifecycle for inactive Change Sets is eventually added, since this feature is still [less than a year old](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-change-sets-for-aws-cloudformation/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have Cloudtrail enabled and if the changeset was created and executed in the last 90 days you may be able to find the content of the change set.

First, in Cloudtrail search for `CreateChangeSet` or `ExecuteChangeSet` events around the time the change was executed. Once you have found the event you will see that it contains the ARN of the changeset:

- For `CreateChangeSet`: in the `"responseElements"."id"` field.
- For `ExecuteChangeSet`: in the `"requestParameters"."changeSetName"` field.

Once you have the ARN you can use it in the Cloudformation `DescribeChangeSet` API call to get the content of the changeset. For example, using the AWS CLI:

```bash
aws cloudformation describe-change-set --change-set-name <ID_FROM_CLOUDTRAIL_EVENT>
```

Comment: Yeah this works, but seems too complicated